# Should I cache the ServiceWorker file in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I still struggle how to avoid caching problems in Progressive Web Apps. Crucial for any PWA caching is the ability to update the ServiceWorker file (let's call it sw.js). But the details are a bit confusing to me:

- It's okay to execute `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')` on every page load because `register()` updates the app cache or does nothing if everything is up to date -- correct?
- Does it make sense to do something like `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js?' + Date.now())` to avoid HTTP caching? Or am I on the safe side if the server uses ETags?
- Does the browser check the network for an updated sw.js on every pageload? I sometimes don't see it in the network inspector tab.
- If sw.js is in the app cache, does the browser fetch it from there without checking the server for an update?
- I sometimes see ServiceWorker demo scripts that cache themselves like this:

  ```
  self.addEventListener('install', ev => {
      const myCaches = {
          app: {...}, 
          sw: {
              files: [
                  '/sw.js'
              ],
              version: '1'
          }
      }
      for (let name in myCaches) {
          const cacheName = name + '-' + myCaches[name].version
          ev.waitUntil(
              caches.has(cacheName).then(uptodate => {
                  if (uptodate) return true
                  caches
                      .open(cacheName)
                      .then(cache => {
                          cache.addAll(myCaches[name].files)
                      })
              })
          )
          // clear old caches
      }
  })
  ```

Does this make sense, is it good practice? Does it make updating the cache more reliable?

Comment: I'm not sure about ETags, but it seems browsers will be moving towards ignoring HTTP caching for service workers https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw

Comment: That's interesting and seems like a very good idea. I wouldn't rely on it though because it's a pretty new feature and I couldn't find anything similar in either spec or other browsers' documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of the code examples I've seen don't add the service worker file to the cache.  In my experience and from my understanding, it's not necessary for offline mode to work.

The browser will install your service worker for your PWA when you register it.   The browser uses a separate facility for caching and managing service workers.  It's not your responsibility to cache it.

Adding a timestamp to the filename of your service-worker is an anti-pattern.  According to the article on Service Worker Lifecycle, you should [avoid changing the URL of your service worker script](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#avoid-url-change).

What is of greater concern is the point you raised about updating the service worker, how does the browser know when to do that?

Well, according to the section [Updating the service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) from the Service Worker Lifecycle article:

> Most browsers, including Chrome 68 and later, default to ignoring
>   caching headers when checking for updates of the registered service
>   worker script. They still respect caching headers when fetching
>   resources loaded inside a service worker via `importScripts()`. You can
>   override this default behavior by setting the `updateViaCache` option
>   when registering your service worker.
>
> Your service worker is considered updated if it's byte-different to
>   the one the browser already has. (We're extending this to include
>   imported scripts/modules too.) The updated service worker is launched
>   alongside the existing one, and gets its own `install` event.
>
> If your new worker has a non-ok status code (for example, 404), fails
>   to parse, throws an error during execution, or rejects during install,
>   the new worker is thrown away, but the current one remains active.

If you've tested your PWA in offline mode, you'll notice that the browser will produce an error in the console when it tries to retrieve your `sw.js` file.  That's nothing to be concerned about.  As the last point above says, "the current one remains active".

I wonder if people are fixated on this 404 entry in the console for the service worker JavaScript when they test in offline mode and add the service worker file to the cache in a fit of yak shaving?  It probably does a disservice to your site and its users by spending time and disk caching an unnecessary file in the browser.

Comment: Avoiding a 404 might indeed be the only (unconvincing) reason to app-cache sw.js. Not sure about HTTP caching though as I haven't found documentation about other browsers' behaviour. Dynamically adding an HTTP parameter should not cause the same problems as changing the file name.

Comment: Yeah, the caching rules for the service worker aren't well-defined.  In fact, they're in flux and unsurprisingly they differ between browsers.  This is new tech, so it's still getting fleshed out.

Comment: In my experience, it is CRITICAL that you cache the service worker; on an Android test that your app (without the service worker cached) runs offline, close the app, turn off all internet access (wifi, mobile) and then power down the device for 7 hours (I am not making this up). Then turn on the device but do not turn on internet.  Attempt to run the app (in offline mode).  It probably will not work.  The solution is to put the service worker into the cache.  I discovered this in a production environment where the customer turned off the device each night "to charge" and had no wifi there.

Comment: Perhaps the browser for the Android device you were testing on uses different rules for caching the service worker?  For example, it may "respect caching headers" as opposed to "ignoring" as was quoted in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose these things evolve over time.

I just checked my experimental app now.  Whether I include or not the service-worker in the urls to be cached, the pwa always fetches the service-worker whenever it is refreshed.

In fact this is the mechanism used for updating the app by the developer.  When an update is to be made, the service-worker version at the server can be updated, and then when the app detects a new version of s-w, it re-fetches all the cached urls as well. Depending on implementation,the re-fetching may be contingent on a changed checksum or a fingerprint of each file against the ones it had cached.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).